# attr_accessor across multiple classes?

Tags: ruby, class, module, attr-accessor

I have a single module with lots of different classes (divided into separate files). Each class has the same set of `attr_accessor`, so how can I reuse that instead of having to repeat the `attr_accessor` block?

What I'm currently doing....

```
# dog.rb
module Animals
   class Dog
      attr_accessor :name, :color, :age 
   end
end

# cat.rb
module Animals
   class Cat
      attr_accessor :name, :color, :age 
   end
end

# rodent.rb
module Animals
   class Rodent
      attr_accessor :name, :color, :age 
   end
end
```

I tried doing this with no luck...

```
# animals.rb
module Animals
   attr_accessor :name, :color, :age 
end
```

I need to access these modules directly across my app (it's a Rails app). For example: `Animals::Dog.give_water`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your use of the module `Animal` is wrong. Using it as a namespace does not do anything good for your purpose. You should include them.

```
module Animals
  attr_accessor :name, :color, :age 
end

class Dog
  include Animals
end

class Cat
  include Animals
end

class Rodent
  include Animals
end
```

Or, you can turn `Animal` into a class, and subclass from that.

```
class Animals
  attr_accessor :name, :color, :age 
end

class Dog < Animals
end

class Cat < Animals
end

class Rodent < Animals
end
```

By the way, a class already implies that it has possibly multiple instances, so it is redundant to have a plural name for a class. And you are also inconsistent about it.

Comment: I need to be able to access methods in each class directly, like `Animals::Dog.feed`...can I still do that with either/both of these?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that. You should elaborate on that in the question.

Comment: @Shpigford yes you can do that with the second example, by defining a method like so; `def self.feed`. It would have to go inside the `Animals` class if you want all the descendants to inherit it.